# Не выполняется код внутри функции горутины

Tags: golang

Есть программа-работник, основанная на каналах, то есть я указываю количество работников (горутин), допустим 16, выполняю функцию, функция - бесконечная, то есть она будет выполняется бесконечное количество раз в 16 горутинах, остановить можно только если послать сигнал о завершении `*chan bool`, но это не работает, у меня вообще не хочет начинать работу, я подозреваю что проблема в том что нужно добавить

```
var s string
fmt.Scanln(&s)
```

Но тогда мне нужно принудительно будет нажимать любую из кнопок для завершении программы или её действия, а мне это категорически не нужно, подскажите, в чем моя проблема. Вот код:

```
type st struct {
    workers int
    stop *chan bool
}

func main() {
    s := st{workers: 16}
    s.run()
    time.Sleep(2 *time.Second)
    s.pstop()
}

func (s *st) pstop() {
    for i := 0; i < s.workers; i++ {
        (*s.stop) <- true
    }
    close(*s.stop)
}

func (s *st) run() {
    schan := make(chan bool)
    s.stop = &schan 

    for i := 0; i < s.workers; i++ { 
        go func() {
            for {
                select {
                case <- (*s.stop):
                    return
                default:
                    fmt.Println("hello")
                }
            }
        }()
    }
}
```

Comment: Не понятно в какой момент приложение должно остановится, а вообще если есть необходимость ждать выполнение горутин то можно использовать sync.WaitGroup{}

Comment: @ЕвгенийГаврилов так я же в функции main объявил что работает 2 секунды и после 2 секунд - стоп, это нужно сделать не дожидаясь работы других горутин, чтоб получилось всё максимально быстро, то есть можно так сказать принудительно.

Comment: Нет нужды использовать указатель на канал, т.к. канал сам по себе уже reference type, как и map и slice.

Comment: У меня всё работает https://play.golang.org/p/jqpacjADJyy

Comment: @IvanBlack спасибо! И в правду работает